# Calling a Programatic Inner Join in VB ResultSets

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, resultset

We have an item cull that retrieves items and their appropriate data from one server.  Their Primary Keys need to be `INNER JOIN`ed with another table.  However, the second table is on another server.  We can retrieve that data using a separate select statement and accompanying VB objects.

How would one go about this programmatically in VB?  Is a loop the best practice available?  Although we are in a Microsoft Ecosystem, Server Linking is not possible.

Comment: Could you help to provide your table structure and sample data, expected result?

Comment: It's just a standard Inner Join.

Comment: Just to clarify you mean vb 6.0 or vba and not vb.net

Comment: @ConradFrix Well that's kinda the point.  I don't really want to do a loop-inside-a-loop, but I will if I have to.  Just kinda seeing if anyone else had a better idea.

Comment: @ConradFrix this is VB.Net 10.0

Comment: @zwerdlds doh I didn't realize that you were answering Thit, rather than just some random person commentating on the question.

Comment: Removing the word 'Union' from the question clears up any confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use openrowset statement.

Syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI10', 
       'server=REMOTEDBSERVERNAME;database=DBNAME;uid=USERID;pwd=PASSWORD', 
       'SELECT * FROM   table')
```

Try it.

Tiz

Comment: This is exactly appropriate for what I need.  Thank you very much.